# How to initialise the second member of an anonymous structure in C?

Tags: c, struct, initialization, anonymous, unions

I have made a structure for ints and pointers etc. as might be used in LISP.

A pointer is at least 8-byte aligned so tag=0.
An integer is 29 bits and has a tag of 1.
Other types have different tag values.

```
struct Atom{
  union{
    Pair              *pair;
    struct{
      unsigned        tag     :3;
      union{
        int           val     :29;
        char          ch;
        struct{
          int         mant    :21;
          Exp         exp     :8;
        };
      };
    };
  };
};
```

I would like to initialise them differently.

For pointers:

```
Atom aPair = {{.pair=0}}; // works
```

or

```
Atom aPair = {{0}}; //works
```

This works because, I assume, GCC assumes that I want to initialise the first member of the union.

I'd also like to initialise an integer - something like this:

```
Atom anInt={{ {.tag=1,{.val=0} } }};
```

I know this is not standard C, but is this possible at all with anonymous structures in GCC?

Comment: There was an answer that I commented on - where did it go?

Someone kindly suggested that I try Atom anInt={.tag=1,.val=0};

It didn't work, but It was something that I hadn't tried and I appreciated that they took time to read my question and suggest something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [known bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10676).

... which has been fixed in gcc 4.6 (using `struct Atom anInt={{ .tag=1, {.val=0} }};`).

Comment: Thank you. I did not consider that the compiler might be at fault.